How to append 2 different columns and move the new data at the end of the new column?
I have 2 worksheets in google spreadsheet that gathers data from user using 2 different google forms.
I have to append the columns from both the worksheets in a 3rd worksheet, which I have been able to do using Vstack formula. However everytime new data is added in the first sheet, it is pushed in between the available data in appended sheet.
I want to move the new data added in any of the sheet to move in the last row of the 3rd work sheet automatically.
I have tried using to append 2 column from 2 different google worksheet in a thrid worksheet by using vstack in a 3rd google worksheet. The formula is working fine, however the issue is whenever the data is added in the 1st worksheet it moves in between the data set in appended (3rd worksheet) while the data added in the 2nd worksheet moves in the last cell of the appended (3rd worksheet). I want the new added data to move in the last cell of the appended workshet (3rd worksheet) no matter in which sheet (1st or 2nd) it is added.

When google form responses store to sheet, there is a column named time_stamp which store date and time automatically. Use QUERY() or SORT() function to sort by that column as ascending. So, new data will go bottom always.
